# Put text on image in button + WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml

everyone, i want to create the button as attached image [Button Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tv6XK.png). I want to put text on the image. Does anyone have came across this situation? Please help me with this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could put text on top of an Image by adding a TextBlock to the same Grid as the Image, e.g.:

```
<Button>
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
            <Grid>
                <Image Source="pic.png" Stretch="None" />
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">Operation</TextBlock>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

If you want to rotate the text you could apply a RotateTransform to it:

```
<Button>
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
            <Grid>
                <Image Source="pic.png" Stretch="None" />
                <TextBlock Text="Operation" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                    <TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
                        <RotateTransform Angle="-90" />
                    </TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
                </TextBlock>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```